# invalid type (list) for variable

Tags: list, dataframe, ggplot2

What's the difference between these two data.frames? and why can I run `swimmer_plot` on one and not the other?

When I run `swimmer_plot` on the `ClinicalTrial.Arm` data.frame, it works fine. If I substitute in the `fdd` data.frame, then I get the error.

I tried to structure `fdd` exactly the same as `ClinicalTrial.Arm`. Only the first three columns are needed for the plot... can't see why this doesn't work.

```
> str(ClinicalTrial.Arm)
'data.frame':   53 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ id                 : num  1 2 2 2 3 3 4 5 5 6 ...
 $ Arm                : chr  "Arm A" "Arm A" "Off Treatment" "Arm A" ...
 $ End_trt            : num  3.26 2 10 15.45 5 ...
 $ Continued_treatment: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Sex                : chr  "F" "F" "F" "F" ...
 $ Age                : chr  ">=65" "<65" "<65" "<65" ...

> str(fdd)
tibble [38 × 3] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id     : num [1:38] 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 ...
 $ Arm    : chr [1:38] "bloodD15" "bloodsurg" "surgery" "bloodD15" ...
 $ End_trt: num [1:38] 14 28 29 15 29 29 57 14 28 28 ...

> swimmer_plot(df=fdd,id='id',end='End_trt',name_fill='Arm',col="black",id_order='Arm')
```

> Error in model.frame.default(formula = df[, end] ~ df[, id]) :
> invalid type (list) for variable 'df[, end]'

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `fdd`, which is a tibble, into a dataframe using `as.data.frame`. Then, you can plot as normal.

```
library(swimplot)

fdd <- as.data.frame(fdd)
swimmer_plot(
  df = fdd2,
  id = 'id',
  end = 'End_trt',
  name_fill = 'Arm',
  col = "black",
  id_order = 'Arm'
)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
fdd <-
  structure(
    list(
      id = c(1, 1, 1, 2),
      Arm = c("bloodD15", "bloodsurg",
              "surgery", "bloodD15"),
      End_trt = c(14, 18, 29, 15)
    ),
    class = c("tbl_df",
              "tbl", "data.frame"),
    row.names = c(NA,-4L)
  )
```